# HashSet does not realize that two objects are the same

Tags: java, hashset

I have looked at the other times this question has been asked on StackOverflow, but none of the other use cases seem to solve my problem. [HashSet does not seem to realize that two objects are the same.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692426/hashset-does-not-seem-to-realize-that-two-objects-are-the-same)

Basically, this is my class.

```
private static class Inconsistency
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        boolean isConsistency;


        //Default constructor. To be used when we don't have an inconsistency
        public Inconsistency()
        {
            this.a = -1;
            this.b = -1;
            this.isConsistency = false;
        }

        public Inconsistency(int a, int b, boolean isConsistency)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.isConsistency = isConsistency;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            if (this.isConsistency) 
            {
                return "(" + this.a + ", " + this.b + ")";
            } 
            else 
            {
                return "No inconsistency";
            }

        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + a;
            result = prime * result + b;
            result = prime * result + (isConsistency ? 1231 : 1237);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other)
        {

            if (this == other)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (other == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (this.getClass() != other.getClass()) 
            { 
                return false; 
            }

            Inconsistency otherInconsistency = (Inconsistency) other;
            return ((this.a == otherInconsistency.a) && (this.b == otherInconsistency.b) && (this.isConsistency == otherInconsistency.isConsistency))
                || ((this.a == otherInconsistency.b) && (this.b == otherInconsistency.a) && (this.isConsistency == otherInconsistency.isConsistency));
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to store objects of my class inside a hashmap.

With the way I'm defining my equals method, an Inconsistency A (10, 20, true), should be equal to another Inconsistency B (20, 10, true) and when I test my equals method, this works correctly. However, when I try to insert both A and B into a HashSet, they both erroneously get added. I understand that I should manipulate my hashcode function but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Here's a driver showcasing the erroneous behaviour

```
    Inconsistency A = new Inconsistency(10,20, true);
    Inconsistency B = new Inconsistency(20,10, true);

    System.out.println(A.equals(B)); // prints true as expected


    HashSet<Inconsistency> test = new HashSet<>();
    test.add(A);
    test.add(B);

    System.out.println(test); // prints [(10, 20), (20, 10)]. The two objects are equal but are both added to hashset
```

Just so the question is clear, How do I go about making sure that the two equal objects A and B both won't be added to my HashSet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your definition of `equals` means that two `Inconsistency` objects with their elements reversed are `.equals`, but your definition of `hashCode` does *not* return the same hash code if `a` and `b` are in a different order, which is a requirement if a `HashSet` or other hash-based collection is to work properly.

The simplest approach to fixing this is to do something commutative -- something that has the same result whichever order `a` and `b` are in.  For example:

```
result = prime * result + a + b;
```

instead of

```
result = prime * result + a;
result = prime * result + b;
```