# How HashSet is working when adding variable

Tags: java, duplicates, hashset

As I know HashSet is not adding duplicate variable, but if I have the code:

```
public class A {
int i, j;
public A(int i, int j) {
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<A> s = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    s.add(new A(3,1));
    s.add(new A(1,3));
    s.add(new A(3,1));
    s.add(new A(3,1));
    s.add(new A(2,1));
    System.out.println(s.size());
}
```

To make sure to not duplicate the variable when I add them to `s`, I need to override `HashCode` and `equals`, but I want to know how Set is working when he adds some variables to the list? What did he check to verify that the Object are not duplicate?

Comment: Look up how a hash table works.

Comment: "*To make sure to not duplicate the variable when I add them to s, **I need to override HashCode and equals***" ... "*What did he check to verify that the Object are not duplicate?*" You literally wrote the answer in the previous sentence.

Comment: Yes, but how did he check it to print the size. For example, to print that the size if 4, how I need here to implement hashcode and equals

Comment: What do you mean how? Is your question about how to properly implement `hashCode` and `equals`?

Comment: No, my question is if there is a way to implement `hashCode` and `equals` so that the size of the `HashSet` in the main will be 4

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question at all. But regardless, I'm not sure why it would ever be 4? You have 3 duplicates (`A(3, 1)`) so the size would be 3?

Comment: @PedroGómez All you need to do is to implement equals() so that it works correctly, then any version if hashCode() that satisfies the contract will work, even ``return 1;``. I'm not saying to do that, but it will work for this assignment.

Answer (score 2):

A `HashSet` is actually a `HashMap` where the value is always the same.

The way a `HashMap` / `hashtable` work is,
***It generates hashes of keys (objects) and positions them into a table. Then each time you look for a key, its hash is computed and the bucket in the table is referenced directly.***

This means you have just one operation (best case) to access the map.
The `HashSet` simply contains the keys, So `.contains(..)` gives time-complexity of O(1) and `remove(..)` also give the time-complexity of O(1) they are the only operations of a `HashSet`, So it is faster than an ArrayList which have a time complexity of O(n). Iteration is giving the same time complexity.

Comment: Thanks! So for example for this case, can I create a hashcode so that the size will be 4?

Comment: Yes, you can create, right now what's happening is you create `objects` and each 'object` is unique, you can follow this to get and idea of implementing with unique objects https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692426/hashset-does-not-seem-to-realize-that-two-objects-are-the-same